# Format returning date format on Symfony2 FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

Is there any way to change the returning date format on a Webservice built with FOSRestBundle in Symfony2?

For example, this is my actual return:

{"id":9,"nome":"Guilherme","rg":"0000000000","cpf":"000.000.000-00",**"nascimento":"1989-06-24T00:00:00+0200"**,"genero":"M"}

I want to change to this:

{"id":9,"nome":"Guilherme","rg":"0000000000","cpf":"000.000.000-00",**"nascimento":"1989-06-24"**,"genero":"M"}

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type, FosRestBundle will look for JMSSerializer first to serialize your entity

Comment: Nice! The annotation @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>") works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's just to add this annotation to the property:

```
@Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
```

See more:
http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type